# change the class of an element without ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the class of an element that has no ID, so I am doing this

```
var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('input-box');
        for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
         cols[i].toggleClass('invisible');
        }
```

but it wont work. I get an error that says

```
cols[i].toggleClass is not a function
```

Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: you are mixing jquery with vanilla javascript. In vanilla javascript, you can do `cols[i].classList.toggle('invisible')`. In jquery, see @Kiran's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `$(cols).toggleClass('invisible');` because your `cols` is not an jquery object and `toggleClass` is a jquery method.

```js
var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('input-box');
        //for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
         //cols[i].toggleClass('invisible');
        //}
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $(cols).toggleClass('invisible');
});
```

```css
.invisible {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="Input 1" class="input-box"/><br/>
<input value="Input 2" class="input-box"/><br/>
<input value="Input 3" class="input-box"/><br/>
<input value="Input 4" class="input-box"/><br/>
<button>Click Me </button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a JQuery function from a non jquery object.

If you are using JQuery you can do something like this:

`$('.input-box').toggleClass('invisible');`

Without JQuery:

```
var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('input-box');
for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
   cols[i].classList.toggle('invisible');
}
```